# Fluentbit Regex support in Match for Filter plugins

Tags: fluent, fluent-bit

I have a basic question about the usage of `Match` for `Filter` plugins.
I saw that `Match` supports wildcard, based on https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/concepts/data-pipeline/router
Is it only basic wildcard support or complete regex support?
My typical tags look like `part1.part2.part3.part4`

This is my current configuration and it works as expected (i.e. logs that match these tags are getting throttled).

```
    [FILTER]
        Name                      throttle
        Match                     part1.*.*.part4
        Rate                      1
        Window                    300
        Interval                  1s
```

I tried to modify this so that this filter is not applied if `part2=xyz`

```
    [FILTER]
        Name                      throttle
        Match                     part1.(?!xyz).*.part4
        Rate                      1
        Window                    300
        Interval                  1s
```

But looks like this isn't working (i.e. none of the logs are getting throttled)

**My questions**:

1. Does it only support basic wildcard support or has complete regex support?
2. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do in the throttle plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

TIL: there is a key named `Match_Regex` and it works in all the places where `Match` can be used.
`Match` only support * as a wildcard
`Match_Regex` supports whole regex

Source: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.3/configuration/file

My modified config

```
    [FILTER]
        Name                      throttle
        Match_Regex               part1.(?!xyz).*.part4
        Rate                      1
        Window                    300
        Interval                  1s
```

Thanks to Anurag Gupta for pointing to this in Fluentbit slack.